# How to select maximum records from timestamp and do the operation using LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    e_id        NUMBER(10),
    f_name      VARCHAR2(50),
    created_on  TIMESTAMP,
    created_by  VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'a','18-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM','aa');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'b','18-07-22 11:06:19.566000000 PM','bb');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'c','16-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM','cc');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'a','15-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM','dd');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'a','12-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM','ee');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'a','11-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM','ff');

DB version: Oracle 18c
```

I need to populate maximum `created_on`, ````` created_by````, and ````` f_name``` from the following logic:

`created_on:` MAX(created_on)

`created_by:` MAX(created_by)

`f_name:` First need to find out the maximum `created_on` in our dataset it would be `'18-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM'` and `'18-07-22 11:06:19.566000000 PM'` and need to populate `f_name` column value in delimiter separated i.e `a;b` for which I will use LISTAGG.

My Attempt:

```
WITH a AS(SELECT e_id, MAX(created_on)created_on,MAX(created_by)created_by
FROM test),
b AS(
SELECT e_id, LISTAGG(DISTINCT(f_name))
FROM test WHERE created_on = --need to select MAX created_on for particular date
);

Need to use DISTINCT in LISTAGG because there may be same records present for an e_id
```

Expected output:

```
+------+--------------------------------+------------+--------+
| e_id |           created_on           | created_by | f_name |
+------+--------------------------------+------------+--------+
|   11 | 18-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM | aa         | a;b    |
+------+--------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Please describe, how does maximum `created_on` can have two values: `18-07-22 12:06:19.566000000 PM` and `18-07-22 11:06:19.566000000 PM`. Do you mean that you need to aggregate `f_name` for the latest date (without time)?

Comment: I believe this LISTAGG(DISTINCT(f_name))  will not work in 18 c ?

Comment: @astentx Yes need to aggregate ```f_name``` based on the latest date. And in timestamp there are two values because they got loaded on different time interval on the same day

Comment: @VBokaMmm nice catch. Since I was using 19c earlier so thought it will work here also

Comment: Hi @Vicky checking the answer you accepted it looks like your "Expected output:" is not truly represented in your question so dwnvote.

Comment: Also, you said in your question: "Need to use DISTINCT in LISTAGG because there may be same records present for an e_id" and this accepted solution will not select distinct... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0de1664d1ac34fd26af8157330cbbee2

Comment: @Vboka Thanks for pointing out this. Yes, I do have thoughts on the accepted answer, and the reason behind why I have accepted this answer even after this is not the expected output. From a business perspective, if we think then I am fetching max created on DateTime and at the same time need to fetch all the f_names on that date. So, if we are fetching all the f_names then better to fetch the user who has created that particular record. So MT0 thought this from a business perspective. Hence, requesting you to please upvote as it may lead to the blocking of an account.

Comment: Never hear of such thing: "Hence, requesting you to please upvote as it may lead to the blocking of an account." ?? And I stand by what I said... Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added one more row to the demo table to demonstrate situation you mentioned: "Need to use DISTINCT in LISTAGG because there may be same records present for an e_id".

I do not see why you need something like this but here is my try to do it:

```
with cte as (select distinct e_id, f_name, trunc(created_on) created_on, created_by 
             from test)
, cte2 as (select e_id, created_on, created_by 
           from test 
           where created_on in (select max(created_on) from test))
select cte.e_id
       , cte2.created_on
       , cte2.created_by
       , listagg(cte.f_name, ';') within group (order by cte.f_name)
from cte
join cte2 on cte.e_id = cte2.e_id and cte.created_on = trunc(cte2.created_on)
group by cte.e_id
       , cte2.created_by
       , cte2.created_on
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e951feb2e3111649d14e0f1bf9f5fa60)

Answer (score 2):

You can `RANK` the rows by `created_on` and then filter to only include those rows with the maximum rank:

```sql
SELECT e_id,
       MAX(created_on),
       LISTAGG(created_by, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_name)
         AS created_by,
       LISTAGG(f_name, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_name)
         AS f_names
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e_id ORDER BY created_on DESC) AS rnk
    FROM   test t
  )
  WHERE rnk = 1
)
GROUP BY e_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (e_id, f_name, created_on, created_by) AS
SELECT 11,'a', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-18 12:06:19.566000000','aa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'b', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-18 23:06:19.566000000','bb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'c', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-16 12:06:19.566000000','cc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'a', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-15 12:06:19.566000000','dd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'a', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-12 12:06:19.566000000','ee' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'a', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-11 12:06:19.566000000','ff' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | E_ID | MAX(CREATED_ON) | CREATED_BY | F_NAMES |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 11 | 18-JUL-22 23.06.19.566000000 | bb | b |

*Note: `a` is not included as it is not the maximum.*

If you want the rows with the maximum date (but not time component) then:

```sql
SELECT e_id,
       MAX(created_on),
       LISTAGG(created_by, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_name)
         AS created_by,
       LISTAGG(f_name, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_name)
         AS f_names
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e_id ORDER BY TRUNC(created_on) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM   test t
  )
  WHERE rnk = 1
)
GROUP BY e_id
```

Which outputs:

> | E_ID | MAX(CREATED_ON) | CREATED_BY | F_NAMES |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 11 | 18-JUL-22 23.06.19.566000000 | aa;bb | a;b |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=584e743f4331ed40b0b9de3df3cfb93b)*